# can not print the complete modal body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i create a modal with jquery and make it printable but i can't figure out how to print the complete modal body. it only prints a part of it. i tryed to use inline page breaks(i saw it in another post) with jquery every few divs but it doesn't work. Anyone had the same problem? I would like some help

Here is the css i use, which i found from another post

css:

```
@media print {
    body.modalprinter * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content {
        border-width: 0;
    }

    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content .modal-header .modal-title,
    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content .modal-body,
    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content .modal-body * {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content .modal-header,
    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content .modal-body {
        padding: 0;
    }

    body.modalprinter .modal-dialog.focused .modal-content .modal-header .modal-title {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

The jquery that goes with it

jquery:

```
    $('.modal.printable').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-dialog', this).addClass('focused');
        $('body').addClass('modalprinter');

        if ($(this).hasClass('autoprint')) {
            window.print();
        }
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-dialog', this).removeClass('focused');
        $('body').removeClass('modalprinter');
    });
```

i Create the modal in html with the modal body empty and on print button i use onClick() The modal body fills from jquery and its content isn`t always the same

```
<div class='modal fade printable ' id='myModal'>
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5"><h3 class='modal-title'>Firma etairias</h3></div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><h4 class=" text-right" id="modal_cust"><span class="small">Πελατης: </span><span id="modal_cust"> </span></h4></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"><button class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button></div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- end modal-header-->
            <div class='modal-body' id="repeater">


            </div><!-- end modal-body-->

            <div class='modal-footer'>
              <button id="btnPrint" class='btn btn-default'  type='button' onclick="window.print();"><span>Print</span></button>  <button class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' type='button'>Close</button> <button class='btn btn-primary' type='button'>Save changes</button>
            </div><!-- end modal-footer -->
        </div><!-- end modal-content -->
    </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- end myModal -->
```

Comment: Can you create a small example of the problem with the CSS and HTML of your modal?

Comment: Why do you use body.modalprinter * { visibility: hidden; }? Maybe by doing this and not defining visibility for all the items in the rest of your CSS, you're hiding part of the modal you want to print.

Comment: the  body.modalprinter * { visibility: hidden; } works the problem appears when the content of the modal body is longer than a A4 page